# ThunderBird fail to receive some mails

Tags: thunderbird

A couple of days ago, I switched from Outlook to ThunderBird, at first I thought it was ok, until today I found that Outlook can receive some mails but ThunderBird cannot! What the heck?

It's like this, say 10 mails to sent by different people, Outlook can receive them all, but ThunderBird can only got 3 or 4 of them, which is wired that how could ThunderBird misses some of those mails? This really drives me crazy, and I decided to give ThunderBird one last shot before I switch back to Outlook.

About my ThunderBird configuration, sending server and receiving server are the same, email.my_company.com.
sending protocol is SMTP, receiving protocol is POP3.

Any idea, bros?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that Outlook is still running, and still downloading the emails and then deleting them from the server.  Thunderbird only gets what it can before Outlook nukes them.

Comment: I agree with Paul. Perhaps Outlook is configured to delete emails after download and Thunderbird configured to leave them on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Thunderbird has got a weird way to check emails. If it does not get all the emails in 60 seconds, it declares that it fails to receive the emails. So if you get an enough big mail with heavy attached documents, 60 seconds will not be enough for Thunderbird to get it and it will not be able to receive emails until you see the big email with an other program like a webmail or Outlook (since it cannot see it). More than 12 MB of attachments can cause this. I don't know why 60 seconds and how to change it.

Comment: But there are some emails which are received by Outlook are just a few `kb`, not more than 1 `mb`, but thunderbird cannot receive them. It's really wierd.